# Improving Winforms performance with large number of controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Are there any ways to improve performance when constructing several forms with large numbers of controls (500+)?

Our controls are laid out in a label + 6 text box per row configuration, as shown below:

[image]

We have used the following containers to structure our controls:

- DevExpress' XtraLayoutControl
- Panels around each row and moving manually
- Common table control

We can't use a grid as the text boxes have to be hidden on a case-by-case basis and our forms have to look fairly close to the printouts. Also, each row has it's own data type, so we need to add validation and editors for each.

The table control is the most performant, where each form takes around 2 seconds to load.

As each of these will represent a document in our software and we allow users to open multiple documents at once, we are trying to find a way to improve the performance.

One suggestion was to cache the actual form and have a state object that stores the data. However, we allow the user to see more than one document at once.

Another suggestion was to load the document in parts and show each part as it becomes loaded. This isn't ideal as we are known for having a document that looks almost exactly like the printout.

Are there any other strategies available, or should we just bight the bullet at tell our customers that this program will be slower than it's VB6 predecessor?

An example of the form design we're redeveloping is here: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120912051058/http://www.twisoftware.com/docs/weldingsoftware/Weldspec-ASME-PQR.pdf)

Comment: I'm very naive about oop but, do you really have to submit all of those data at the same time? (i'm assuming you have only 1 button)

If i were you, i would add put only first 2 lines of your gui. And i would provide a loop that tells user to type metal specification 2 then 3rd then 4th.. (a)

Comment: Hi Timur, this is a program that doesn't really have the kind of flow you're talking about here. The user fills the details in a kind of top down order, but not explicitly. This is a test setup, the full document is much more complicated and a lot less linear

Comment: For example: http://www.twisoftware.com/docs/weldingsoftware/Weldspec-ASME-PQR.pdf

Comment: Solution: WPF. Winforms sucks and is slow as hell.

Comment: Brass won't buy that i'm afraid. none of the team have any exclusive experience in WPF so development time will skyrocket :(

Comment: I just created the same screen in WPF (with 40 lines of C# code and 20 lines of XAML) and  it works perfect even with data (textboxes are filled with "Value1", "Value2", etc.

Comment: Only 20 lines of XAML? How did you implement 200 odd controls in that? Each row has it's own set of values and is databound with different data types unfortunately.

Comment: @Darkzaelus See my answer. I might provide more info on how to construct the complex datatype bindings if you show us how the data looks like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complex datatype handling and stuff is to you, this is a 5 minute before-lunch sample to show how much winforms sucks and how much WPF rules:

```
namespace WpfApplication5
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<Item> _items;
    public List<Item> Items
    {
        get { return _items ?? (_items = new List<Item>()); }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Items.Add(new Item() {Description = "Base metal Thickness"});

        for (var i = 32; i > 0; i--)
        {
            Items.Add(new Item() {Description = "Metal Specification " + i.ToString()});
        }

        Items.Add(new Item() { Description = "Base metal specification" });

        DataContext = this;
    }
}

public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<string> _values;
    public List<string> Values
    {
        get { return _values ?? (_values = new List<string>()); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Description { get; set; }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) 
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public Item()
    {
        Values.Add("Value1");
        Values.Add("Value2");
        Values.Add("Value3");
        Values.Add("Value4");
        Values.Add("Value5");
        Values.Add("Value6");
    }
}
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Width="130"/>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=.}" Margin="2" Width="90"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

I see that you have several other requirements here, such as hiding texboxes and stuff. It doesn't matter if these rows are a different data type, you just need to do a **ViewModel** (which in this case would be my `public class Item`, which hold the data you want to show in the screen, and let the user be able to interact with.

For example, you could replace the `List<string>` inside the `Item` class with something more complex, and add some properties like `public bool IsVisible {get;set;}` and so on.

I strongly suggest you take a look at WPF (at least for this screen in particular).

Copy and paste my code in a new -> WPF project and you can see the results for yourself.

Comment: Good lord. We've created a mock up of the document in WPF and it takes around 70ms to load, compared to 1000ms for winforms! Sorry I was so skeptical, it just seemed a little ridiculous!

Comment: @Darkzaelus do yo see? winforms should be automatically deprecated by everyone just based on the above comment. Not to mention the ease of development provided by the Binding Framework and other advanced features of WPF. Also, take a look a the `Document` classes in WPF, which may help you build wysiwyg forms (such as `System.Windows.Documents.FixedDocument`)

Comment: Will do! I agree with you, although binding is still a little alien to me, I do see it is very powerful. I love reactive programming!

Answer (score 2):

`We can't use a grid as the text boxes have to be hidden on a case-by-case basis.`

I don't understand why this precludes the use of a `DataGridView`. A specific `DataGridViewCell` can be made read-only by setting the `ReadOnly` property to `true`. You could then use the `DataGridView.CellFormatting` event to hide the value of the read-only cells. If I recall correctly, the code would be similar to this:

```
private void grid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView grid = (DataGridView)sender;
    if (grid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ReadOnly)
    {
        e.Value = string.Empty;
        e.FormattingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ginosaji, please see my edit for an example of the form we're redeveloping. Our software is known for the form being edited looking the same as the printout. Unfortunately we can't do this approach. Also, each row has it's own separate data type. And they're databound. I have too many restrictions and not enough options!

Comment: You could create a consistent `ViewModel` for the rows to bind to. Concrete implementations of the `ViewModel` would perform the various conversions to/from the underlying data types. However, the example form you posted looks like you would be better off using multiple `DataGridView` controls, rather than trying to shoehorn it all into one grid.