# Out of memory exception in (System.Drawing())

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I am having trouble rotating an image. The size of the image I'm trying to rotate is around 300kB. When I rotate it from the zero degree to 360, increasing the angle one degree at a time, I get an out of memory exception. It is working until 100 degree.

Here's my code:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory  = System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer .ToString ();

    DialogResult result = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        String pathfile = this.openFileDialog1.FileName ;
        meter = Image.FromFile(pathfile);

        pictureBox1.Image = meter;

        bitmapmeter = new Bitmap(meter);
        gmeter = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapmeter);
        w = bitmapmeter.Width;
        h = bitmapmeter.Height;
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle = angle + 1)
    {
        bitmapmeter = new Bitmap(meter);    //create a bitmap for selected image//pictureBox2.Image = bitmapmeter;
        gmeter = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapmeter);

        rotate(angle);

        bitmapmeter.Dispose();

        gmeter.Dispose();
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Finished");
}

Bitmap newBitmap;
Graphics graphics;

private void rotate(int angle)
{
    newBitmap = new Bitmap(w, h);
    graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap);

    graphics.TranslateTransform((float)bitmapmeter.Width / 2, (float)bitmapmeter.Height / 2);
    graphics.RotateTransform(1);
    graphics.TranslateTransform(-(float)bitmapmeter.Width / 2, -(float)bitmapmeter.Height / 2);
    graphics.DrawImage(bitmapmeter, new Point(0, 0));

    newBitmap.Dispose();
    graphics.Dispose();
    //pictureBox2.Image = bitmapmeter;
}
```

Comment: Winforms will make you suffer trying to do these kind of things. [WPF will make you happier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710117/updating-ui-in-c-sharp-using-timer/14711744#14711744)

Comment: Why do you create 720 instances of `Bitmap` and `Graphics` if you need only two (original and rotated)? Of course, you can call `GC.Collect()`, but it would be better to totally re-write the code.

Comment: Your `rotate` method doesn't even return a image.  Does this even work like you expect it to?

Comment: @NikolayKhil - He actually doesn't create 720 instances of `Bitmap` and `Graphics` its actually only 360.

Comment: @NikolayKhil - I only see `rotate(int angle)` being called 360 times.

Comment: @Ramhound - The OP is creating a new Bitmap in the for loop and then again in the rotate method that is called by the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The order of your Dispose calls should be reversed, the bitmap cannot be disposed because the graphics object is still using it.  Dispose graphics and then the bitmap, reverse order of how you created them.  (and wrapping in a "using" block which automatically disposes will look nicer :)

```
using (bitmapmeter = new Bitmap(meter))    //create a bitmap for selected 
{
  using (gmeter = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapmeter))
  {
    rotate(angle);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

you should throw a GC.Collect in there, you are probably running out of memory before the garbage collector gets a chance to run.

Comment: You shouldn't need to call GC.Collect - garbage collection is optimized to run when it needs to.  If things aren't being cleaned up, it is more likely something is keeping a reference to the objects.

Comment: If you have to call GC.Collect, you have done it wrong, you should never have to mess woith GC, ever.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 [...] in a prod environment.  Messing with it in a development environment can be a useful diagnostic tool.