# Rotating a square without messing the x and y

Tags: c#, vb.net, rotation, gdi+, gdi

So I'm having a bit of trouble getting these coordinates nailed down.

When I do `e.Graphics.RotateTransform(45)` the result is this:

[image: e.Graphics.RotateTransform result]

What I'd like to happen, and what happens in any photo editing software is this:

[image: Desired outcome]

Here's the code. I know the `sqrt(2)` ratio isn't perfect for rotating this, but I'll fix it after I've gotten this down.

Here's the code I use, that produces the faulty output:

```
Using G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Canvas)
        With G

            .TextRenderingHint = Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias
            .CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality
            .SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

            ' ROTATE AT 45 DEGREES
            '.RotateTransform(45)
            .DrawRectangle(New Pen(Color.Black, LineWidth), New Rectangle(New Point((Dims - NewSize) / 2, (Dims - NewSize) / 2), New Size(NewSize, NewSize)))

            ' NON-TRANSFORMED STUFF
            ' G.DrawString("ayy lmoa", New Font(New FontFamily("Arial"), 16, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, New Point(0, 0))
        End With
End Using
```

Has anyone dealt with something like this before?

Comment: _Has anyone dealt with something like this before?_ You must be kidding. There are 10trillion questions and answers about rotating. Why didn't you do your reasearch before adding another one??? You are missing the TranslateTransform to move the origin to the targetted centerpoint. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525965/rotate-a-graphics-bitmap-at-its-center/26527737#26527737)

Comment: If you also want to restrict the site you indeed must calculate the new size for 45° as sqrt(2) or for other angles with trigonomerty. You always should use the new center as the (temporary) origin!

Comment: Okay, so I've tried to implement TranslateTransform. Here's the code: `TranslateTransform(Dims / 2.0F, Dims / 2.0F)` and here's the [result](http://i.imgur.com/vnXcw7W.png).

Comment: This is c#, but you will not find it hard to follow: `int loc = 30;
int size = 50;  int newsize = (int)(size / Math.Sqrt(2));
int center = loc + size / 2;
int nloc = loc + (size  - newsize) / 2;
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new Rectangle(loc, loc, size, size));`

Comment: `e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(center, center);
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(45);
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-center, -center);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(loc, loc, size, size));
e.Graphics.ResetTransform();

e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(center, center);
e.Graphics.RotateTransform(45);
e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-center, -center);
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(nloc, nloc, newsize, newsize));`

Comment: It draws the original, the rotated and the rotated and resized squares