# How do I animate a GIF which is being pulled from the resource folder?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The "shooter" subclass

```
class Shooter : Box
{
    public bool goleft;
    public bool goright;



    public Shooter(float startx, float starty)
    {
        pic = resizeImage (Properties.Resources.shooter, new Size(50,50)); // resize image
        goleft = false;
        goright = false;
        x = startx;
        y = starty;

    }
```

And this is the main class from which it inherited the code.

```
class Box
{
    public Image pic;
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public int speed;

    public Box()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        speed = 0;
    }
    // Image Resizing Code
    public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
    {
        return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
    }
    // image resizing code


    public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawImage(pic, x, y);
    }
    // some code bellow that basically states the borders and hit boxes.
}
```

So, yeah, I'm just trying to figure out how to animate a gif which is essentially built by a constructor... The shooter shows up, I can move it around but the problem is, is that it's just not spinnin'. Hope you guys can figure it out. Thanks :D

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
Always __TAG__ your question correctly!

Comment: It's tagged as c#...

Comment: c# is the language, what's the UI framework you are using is what Taw asked

Comment: oh, it's visual studio.

Comment: Visual Studio is the IDE, which of course you are using it. It seems you are not very clear on the technologies you are using

Comment: @AlcoGoblin "Visual Studio" is not a UI framework, it's an IDE. What project-template did you select for your project?

Comment: It's Windows Forms App (.Net Framework). I don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: I could guess that is is WinForms. The point is that you always should __Tag__ the target so people who scan the [questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=newest&pageSize=30) can see whether it is in their field of expertise. I for example do'nt do ASP or WPF so I can skip those questions..

Comment: @TaW so the only way for me to do it is to kind of redo the code and put it as a picture box?

Comment: To make a gif animation run it neesd to be in a PictureBox.Image. Drawing it will only paint the pixels of the 1st frame.

Comment: Well either that or, if is simly spinning you might consider drawing it rotated in code. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525965/rotate-a-graphics-bitmap-at-its-center/26527737?s=3|37.5728#26527737) for an example

Comment: @TaW  I think it would be simpler for him to derive its `Box` class from `Panel` and use [`ImageAnimator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageanimator(v=vs.110).aspx) to rotate the bitmap frames. It takes care of all the timings..

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe no. For a simple spin it may be fine to draw rotated images, for anything more complicated probably not. __Interesting link__! Thanks! - @ferc may want to include it in the answer..

Answer (score 1):

Your GIF is not being animated because your `Box` class simply doesn't support it.

If you want to animate the image, you can't open it as a Bitmap, you need to get the image data and do the animation manually, or use a PictureBox to display the image. [Here's](http://www.vcskicks.com/csharp_animated_gif.php) an example of how to do it manually. Note that in order to resize the GIF, you also need to do it frame by frame.