# How can I rotate Picture Box in c# in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#

I am not a good programmer. Currently I am working in c#. Can anyone please tell me how I can rotate picture box clock-wise with smooth animation in c#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061856/how-do-i-rotate-a-picturebox-around-a-point

Comment: Controls can't be rotated. You [can rotate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061856/how-do-i-rotate-a-picturebox-around-a-point/37062256?s=1|2.4056#37062256) the Image, though..