# Rotate Rectangle - C#

Tags: c#, graphics, rectangles

I wanna make a rectangle rotate around its center. The rotation works perfectly but I can't figure out how to rotate it around its center. Can someone help me? Thanks! :)
Here is my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Paint += new PaintEventHandler(PaintRectangle);
        angle = 0;
        t = new Timer();
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(DrawRectangle);
        t.Interval = 1;
        t.Start();
    }

    private void DrawRectangle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        angle++;
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void PaintRectangle(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10);
        Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
        g.TranslateTransform(124, 150);
        g.RotateTransform(angle);
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.White, r);
    }
```

Comment: Why would you assign the paint event handler again and again in the button click event?

Comment: Because I wanna rotate it when that button is pressed.

Comment: `Graphics g = CreateGraphics();` ouch! you should use the e.Graphics object. Here ansd __always__!! After the roation set the translate back __by the same amount__, then draw! The amount should be half the rectangle size!

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help me with my problem.

Comment: @TaW, what's that different between `Graphics g = CreateGraphics();` and `Graphics g = e.Graphics;`?

Comment: Only the one from the PaintArgs is valid; the other one produces shaky and (usually) non-persistent results. After making my suggested modifications your works works: `e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(50, 5);
            e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-50, -5);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, r);` Make sure to turn on double-buffering for the form! Also note that a timer will never be faster than 15-25ms!

Comment: You may want to [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450764/how-to-rotate-image-in-picture-box/26455088?s=6|1.4450#26455088) . The trick of the Translate/Rotate/Translate sequence is to move the origin(0,0) to the center of the rotation. Then rotate the port, then move it back. Then draw.

Comment: Thanks, @TaW :) You really helped me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translate all the vertices so that the center of the rectangle would be on `(zero, zero)`. If the center of the rectangle is (x,y), you need to translate all vertices by `(-x,-y)`. Then rotate by any angle and then translate vertices back by `(x,y)`.