# How can I tumble a picturebox in c# form

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I'm trying to write a code that tumbles a picturebox when pressed `Space` key. If we hold the key, the picturebox will enter to a loop like this [image]

What should I use?

Comment: See here: [Image.RotateFlip doesn't seem to rotate the Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53764409/7444103), using the Mouse Pointer instead of a Keyboard key to trigger the animation.

Comment: Oh it helped a lot. Thank you!