# Rotate image in Winforms with C++/CLI

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

The main task is to make roulette wheel image spinning on a given angle. It does not matter whether it is a plane, picture box or something else, the main thing is that it is possible to turn at a clearly defined angle

Current variant rotates it only by 90 degrees

```cpp
pictureBox1->Image->RotateFlip(RotateFlipType::Rotate90FlipNone);
pictureBox1->Refresh();
```

Comment: Just guessing, but isn't there a way to rotate-transform the picture? Edit: [`RotateTransform`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26455088/7582247) in a C# answer. Perhaps you can depickle that.

Comment: as i know, it's for graphics, but i don't know how to convert graphics to image then

Comment: This question is in C#, but I belive a translation to c++/cli (which you seem to use) should be quite straightforward: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163829/how-do-i-rotate-a-picture-in-winforms.

Comment: @L0mTiCk Did you look at the answer? It makes a BMP out of the `PictureBox.Image`, then  `RotateTransform`s that.

Comment: yes, but there are lots of errors, i tried to translate to c++ but I didn't have enough knowledge

Comment: I think you should be looking for C++/CLI solutions. Not C++ solutions as you are apparently programming in C++/CLI, not C++.

Comment: omg, i did i, but there's 1 problem, that after a couple of rotations image becomes blurry

Comment: @L0mTiCk You need to keep the original image and use that for each rotation. Every rotation introduces noise, just like if you kept copying a tape of music in many generations, so always use the original, copy it and then rotate the copy with the target angle.

Answer (score -1):

Answer (the original code in C#: [Rotate picture in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163829/how-do-i-rotate-a-picture-in-winforms)) + it's useless at this moment because of bluring and memory usage increasing:

```
    private: System::Void spinButton_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        pictureBox1->Image = RotateImage(pictureBox1->Image, 15);
    }
    public: Image^ RotateImage(Image^ img, float rotationAngle)
    {
        //create an empty Bitmap image
        Image^ bmp = Image::FromFile("rouletteWheel.png");

        //turn the Bitmap into a Graphics object
        Graphics^ gfx = Graphics::FromImage(bmp);

        //now we set the rotation point to the center of our image
        gfx->TranslateTransform((float)bmp->Width / 2, (float)bmp->Height / 2);

        //now rotate the image
        gfx->RotateTransform(rotationAngle);

        gfx->TranslateTransform(-(float)bmp->Width / 2, -(float)bmp->Height / 2);

        //set the InterpolationMode to HighQualityBicubic so to ensure a high
        //quality image once it is transformed to the specified size               
        gfx->InterpolationMode = System::Drawing::Drawing2D::InterpolationMode::HighQualityBicubic;
        //now draw our new image onto the graphics object

        gfx->DrawImage(img, 0, 0);

        //dispose of our Graphics object
        gfx->~Graphics();

        //return the image
        return bmp;
    }
```

But there's 1 problem, after a couple of rotations image becomes blurry.

Comment: Don't rotate the same image repeatedly, keep the original around so you can always create a fresh new rotated copy.  Attribution is required here btw.

Comment: honestly, I don't quite understand what you wanted to say, but the current method with multiple rotations also greatly increases the memory used

Comment: You have to dispose the image to avoid out-of-control memory usage.  if (pictureBox1->Image != nullptr) delete pictureBox1->Image;   pictureBox1->Image = RotateImage(...);