How to rotate bitmap picture
"Find three more images (or flip the image that you have used) and add them to the project. Change the image to match the direction of movement (you’ll need to add a ChangeImage method to the class for this"
Have to do this but Idk how.
I got it to rotate to the like pressed buttons, i.e i press the left arrow and it faces left, but the image is stuck in the top left corner because I dont know how to change image without setting the position to the current image position. I want to be able to change the direction of the image as it moves, i,e i press to move down and the image flips upside down. And not for it to reset to the top left corner everytime because It asks me to reset a position and idk how to get current coords of the bitmap.
using Basic_Drawing.Properties;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Web;

namespace Basic_Drawing
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Img cat;
    Boolean Left, Right, Up, Down;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        Point position = new Point(100, 100);
        cat = new Img(Resources.cat, position);
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        cat.Draw(e.Graphics);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            Left = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            Right = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            Up = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            Down = true;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            Left = false;
            Point position = new Point(x, y);
            cat = new Img(Resources.cat2, position);
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            Right = false;
            Point position = new Point(x,  y);
            cat = new Img(Resources.cat, position);
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            Up = false;
            Point position = new Point(x, y);
            cat = new Img(Resources.cat, position);
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            Down = false;
            Point position = new Point(x, y);
            cat = new Img(Resources.cat4, position);
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        if (Right && (cat.Location.X + cat.Picture.Width + 5) < 
         this.ClientRectangle.Width)    /*(cat.Location.X < 
        (cat.Picture.Width - this.ClientRectangle.Width)))*/
         {
            x += 5;
        }

        if (Left && (cat.Location.X) - 5 > 0)
        {
            x -= 5;
        }

        if (Up && (cat.Location.Y) - 5 > 0)
        {
            y -= 5;
        }

        if (Down && (cat.Location.Y + cat.Picture.Width + 5) < 
           this.ClientRectangle.Height)                                     
           /*(cat.Location.Y < (cat.Picture.Height - 
           this.ClientRectangle.Height)))*/
        {
            y += 5;
        }

        Point newlocation = new Point(cat.Location.X + x, 
         cat.Location.Y + y);

        cat.Location = newlocation;
        this.Refresh();


    }




 }
}


https://stackoverflow.com/a/61964222/14171304

How does this help me rotate my image in the direction of my arrow keys? Sorry, I am really confused.

More simple examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2163829/14171304 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/76434266/14171304

Still confused? You just need to Image.RotateFlip the image. Pass the corresponding direction RotateFlipType as you change it.
