# What is the WPF answer to this?

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have used WPF to develop two moderately sized applications. I was much impressed by the cleanness of WPF and its features. When I explained to one of my colleagues (Who happens to develop business apps) the various benefits of WPF, he challenged me with this problem which had me totally stumped:

**The Problem:**

He coded an application in the following way in about 2 minutes:

1. Open a new WinForms project.
2. Define a class `Loan`.
3. Build project.
4. Define an object data source using `Loan`.
5. In Data Sources explorer, change view type of the `Loan` data source to Details.
6. Drag the data source onto the Form in the designer.
7. Supply the data source with a `Loan[]` containing one object.
8. Build and run application.

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForms_DataBinding_Example
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            loanBindingSource.DataSource = new Loan[] { new Loan() };
        }
    }

    public class Loan
    {
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public decimal Rate { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get { return Amount * Rate; } }
    }
}
```

The designer:

[image]

The application:

[image]

Now whenever you change the value of `Amount` or `Rate` in the window, the value of `Total` changes accordingly. After explaining that this is a very useful feature in business apps where any changes you make to one property in an entity immediately updates the view where calculated properties are refreshed instantly making the user experience better. Considering that the typical business entity class has a lot of properties, this saves a lot of coding. Then he asked me to do the same in WPF.

I first explained to him that I do not understand what sort of black magic goes on here. How does the `Total` textbox update itself automatically? This is my first question:

Q1. The `Loan` class does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or something similar. So how does the `Total` textbox get updated when the `Amount` or `Rate` textboxes lose focus?

Then I told him that I do not know how to do the same thing so easily in WPF. However, I wrote the same app in WPF with 3 `TextBlock`s and 3 `TextBox`s in the UI. I also needed to make `Loan` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Added backing fields to `Amount` and `Rate`. Whenever these properties were being set, I raised a property changed notification for the property `Total`. In the end, I was left with an app with badly aligned controls which did the same thing as the WinForms app. However, this was way harder to do than the WinForms method.

I came home and then had the bright idea of drag-dropping the `Loan` data source on to the WPF window (After I changed the view mode to detail). Sure enough, I got the same kind of UI as in WinForms app and after setting the data source to the same `Loan[]` as in WinForms app, it seemed to be complete. I ran the app, changed the `Amount` and `Rate` fields hoping to see `Total` change itself automagically. However, I was disappointed. The `Total` field did not change:

[image]

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using WinForms_DataBinding_Example;

namespace WPF_Grid_Example
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource loanViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("loanViewSource")));
            // Load data by setting the CollectionViewSource.Source property:
            loanViewSource.Source = new List<Loan>() { new Loan() };
        }
    }
}
```

The xaml:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:WinForms_DataBinding_Example="clr-namespace:WinForms_DataBinding_Example;assembly=WinForms_DataBinding_Example" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="WPF_Grid_Example.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded_1">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="loanViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type WinForms_DataBinding_Example:Loan}, CreateList=True}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="grid1" DataContext="{StaticResource loanViewSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,123,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Amount:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="amountTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Amount, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
            <Label Content="Rate:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="rateTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Rate, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
            <Label Content="Total:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="totalTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Total, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Q2. I was confounded before by the black magic of WinForms, I was confounded now because the same black magic did not work in WPF. Why?

Q3. How do I make the WPF version to update the `Total` field automatically as in the WinForms example?

Q4. Which platform is better/faster for this sort of business app development? If I am to make a better argument on behalf of WPF, what should I be looking at?

I hope I was clear about the problem. Please let me know if any clarifications are needed. Thanks.

Comment: wow.. I'm impressed, winforms can auto generate a screen with 3 textboxes... so what? anything else is impossible in winforms, whereas WPF gives you the ability to customize EVERYTHING, and bind ANYTHING to ANYTHING, not only, say the Text property, as in winforms. REAL world Line-of-Business applications are not simple textboxes, they require much complex logic than that, and winforms requires a hell of code to do real applications, against simple properties and XAML.

Comment: @HighCore: I am sure you are right. But your comment doesn't answer any of my questions. :(

Comment: In general, I it seems you are comparing two frameworks based on a specific use case. I don't think that leads to fair results.

Comment: Just to be clear : I am using only an example. My colleague is not a complete moron and he does not use plain winforms. He uses at least one well known commercial UI toolkit for developing WinForms apps and they are much better at this sort of thing if I am correct. I am not out to start a holy war pitting WPF vs WinForms. I am just asking four specific questions.

Comment: I don't understand, in the WPF version you start by defining the class loan? with autoproperties and no `INotifyPropertyChanged`? I will try to reproduce this in VS2010, as I think VS 2012 is badly bugged everywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q1: If you look at the designer file for the Windows Form you'll see about 300 lines of code generated for your 3 textboxes.  Some of this code is similar to:

```
this.amountTextBox.DataBindings.Add(
    new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", 
        this.loanBindingSource, "Amount", true));
```

The Binding and the BindingSource co-operate to update the bound values and cause all bound controls to be updated every time one of the values changes (using reflection).

Q2: Because the WPF designer doesn't create a .Designer.cs file and the associated mess of code.  You need to explicitly implement INotifyPropertyChange, which can be simplified by using say MVVM Light's ViewModelBase, e.g.

```
public class Loan : ViewModelBase
{
    public decimal Amount
    {
        get
        {
            return this.amount;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Set(() => Amount, ref this.amount, value))
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Total);
            }
        }
    }
```

Q3: 
1) When Amount or Rate changes raise the property change notification for that property but also for the computed property 'Total'.
2) Modify your bindings on Amount and Rate to `Binding="{Binding Amount, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"`

Q4: WPF no question (IMHO).  The WPF way is more testable and maintainable and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to Q4:

Regardless of winforms having the ability to generate 3 silly textboxes for a class, WPF is a much better, scalable and powerful framework. It has much greater performance due to hardware acceleration and whatnot, and requires less or no code to do some tasks that take tons of code in winforms, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14565773/improving-winforms-performance-with-large-number-of-controls/14566539#14566539), or this:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chk"/>
<TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=chk}"/>
```

Also, tipical Line-of-Business applications have to deal with thousands or hundreds of thousands of records, and [UI Virtualization makes a huge difference](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3Y6DnFpHCA).

The bottom line is that winforms, regardless of having some designer goodies (which are more a feature of Visual Studio than winforms itself), is nowhere near as practical and adequate when it comes to Line of Business.