# Display Properties in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, class

I have a class with a lot of properties like:

```
public class Person
{
   public string Firstname{get;set;}
   public string Lastname{get;set;}
   public string Address{get;set;}
   public string City{get;set;}
   public int ZIPCode{get;set;}
   public string Country{get;set;}
}
```

I want to create a UserControl, where I can pass an instance of Person and show for each Property a TextBlock with the PropertyName and a TextBox with the Property-Value.

My first idea would be to use a grid with two columns and 6 rows. But this is a lot of "work" to type this down.

Is there a "easy" way to achieve this? Can I do this with datatemplates or so?

Comment: Number one it's not a lot of "work". It takes me less than 5 minutes to generate a proper `DataTemplate` for all that. Number two you can do this in the Visual Studio Designer if you want. take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14858573/643085)

Comment: You can either use PropertyGrid or Reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use binding.

You could set the datacontext of the usercontrol to the object and bind to the object's properties.

or you can declare properties in the user control and use binding to bind each textblock to the user control property you just declare.

.

Your pick

Comment: This is clear. But in this solution I have to create all the rows with the labels and the textboxes by hand. the setting of the person-properties into the Textboxes is not the problem.

Comment: Unless you have tons of rows and columns and not acess to copy/paste, I don't see as how this is a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

One easy solution is the use a `PropertyGrid`, such as that in the [extended WPF toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid&referringTitle=Home).